# Hiding "lastest rendered frame" in renderfarm sheepit for confidentiality?

Tags: rendering

Wondering if there is an option in sheepit to hide your project to the users rendering it. By default they can see the frame they rendered. I'm thinking about using it for professional work therefore confidentiality is important.

Comment: Given the current state of affairs in cyber security field, if confidentiality is really an issue then you are probably better off not even involving any internet at all in the whole process, let alone other people's computers.

Answer (score 1):

The core concept of Sheep It involves transferring the project being rendered on other people's machines. As the Sheep It owners have no control over the 3rd party computers, keeping work private is a challenge.

There are, however, paid solutions (for instance, RenderStreet) that can get the job done without breaking the bank and in complete security. As working professionally implies receiving monetary compensation for the projects, the rendering costs can be factored in the project budget.

As a final comment, I would recommend checking the privacy policy of any service you intend to use for professional work.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I would prefer if you had added a reference to the fact you work for RenderStreet, no everyone is going to notice it in your BSE username.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and for the comment, @rob. I thought that the name would make the connection clear, but I'll keep your observation in mind for future posts.